# php excel export - text is broken up into a new line

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export-to-excel

I am fetching mysql data and writing it to xls file, that data contains First Name,Last Name, Email, Address , City, State, Zip.

Every thing is working fine except for the few rows for example

if address string is "1921 s. catalina ave suite 3"

than address field in xls file contains only part of the string "1921 s. catalina" and " ave suite 3" in new line

another example if address string is "22850 crenshaw blvd  suite101"

than address field in xls file contains only part of the string "22850 crenshaw blvd" and " suite101" in new line.

I dont know what is breaking address string to two parts

Comment: Use strip_tags() of PHP. For example strip_tags($row['message']);

Comment: already tried not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the fputcsv function to write as CSV. That will take care of the encoding and also escaping weird characters that break the layout. More details on the PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

**EDIT:** 
OP wanted a XLS format, not CSV, so the trick was to just clean up the string from newline characters using:

```
$xls_string = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $dirty_string);
```

Comment: but what is problem above, i dont need csv

Comment: Hard to say unless you share your actual code. It's probably just a matter of newline characters which you can probably clean up with a pregreplace:  $csv_string = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $dirty_string);

Comment: $csv_string = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $dirty_string);  it works @Alberto

Comment: great! i'll edit the answer so you can accept it and we keep it here so it might help someone else in the future..